# Validation Rule in Property Sheet Not Doing Anything

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am using MS Access 2016

I have two dates, a start date and an end date. I want to make sure that the end date occurs after the start date so I wrote a validation rule in the Property Sheet.

I wrote:

```
[End Date]>=[Start Date]
```

However it does not work. If I put an end date that occurs before the `Start Date`, the entry is still valid.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:

[image]

What I highlighted red is where I get the error:

> "Invalid SQL Syntax - cannot use multiple columns in a column-level
>   CHECK constraint"

Comment: And the data types of the fields are?

Comment: @Gustav They are both Date/Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the validation rule for the field(s) empty. Then, for the table (your yellow marking), set validation rule to:

```
[End Date]>=[Start Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reference [End Date] in the expression, just:

```
 >=[Start Date]
```

And if you want to allow Null:

```
 >=[Start Date] Or Is Null
```

Comment: I get an error. "Invalid SQL Syntax - cannot use multiple columns in a column-level CHECK constraint"

Comment: I am not familiar with that error. I cannot replicate the issue. The suggested code works for me. Are you doing this in a textbox on form? If you want to provide db for analysis, I recommend Box.com fileshare site.

Comment: Maybe we are talking about different places. I added an image to the question with further details.

Comment: Okay, now I get that error. I don't set most properties in table, only in form.